# Naive Bayes 2-class classification, subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

There are two data frames: `trainReady`(288obs.) and `testReady`(112obs.). These data frames contains 55 attributes (54 continuous  and 1 binary, class attribute). I have already discretized those 54 attributes to 10 divisions, levels (with equal number of observations per level assumption). The number of obs. of both classes in `trainReady` is nearly equal. In `testReady` too. Class attribute is treated as factor. Below I am posting pieces of data frames:
**trainReady**  [image: trainReady]

**testReady**
[image]

When I try to run those lines (as you can see I have set the threshold to omit "0-frequency" problem):

```
model_bayes <- naiveBayes(isFace ~ ., data = trainReady)
prediction <- predict(model_bayes, testReady[,-1], threshold = 0.001, eps = 0)
```

I receive:

```
Error in [.default(object$tables[[v]], , nd + islogical[attribs[v]]) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What I have already done to help myself with overcoming the problem:

1. `model_bayes <- naiveBayes(isFace ~ ., data = trainReady, drop.unused.levels = FALSE)`
2. Predicting on the data which had been used to train model:

`prediction <- predict(model_bayes, trainReady[,-1], threshold = 0.001, eps = 0)`
1 does not work, 2 works but I would like to predict on the test data. Could you tell me how can I overcome the problem?

Comment: Please do not provide your data in an image. We do not want to type it all in again to reproduce your problem.  Instead,  please use `dput(testReady)` and `dput(trainReady)` and copy the results to your question so that we can cut and paste into R.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same discretization that you used for training *also* for test data.

Do not diacretize them independently.